# simpilfy sum query with multiple where

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

for example i have an ids of: 1, 2, 3, 4

with that given ids, I want to calculate of a column, let say `value`. how to do this query for each id with just one query? I mean, like

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE id IN('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

is this possible to do so?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `id` is a number, then you shouldn't compare it to a string. `'1'` is a string, `1` is a number.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [group by](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP).

Example:

```
select * from test order by 1

 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   6
  1 |   2
  1 |   4
  2 |   1
  2 |   5
  2 |   3
  3 |   9
  4 |   6
(8 rows)

select id, sum(val)
from test
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by 1
order by 1

 id | sum 
----+-----
  1 |  12
  2 |   9
  3 |   9
  4 |   6
(4 rows)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be what the OP is asking about. It seems he wants to SUM() only the values for rows with id in (1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this situation is to not use the aggregate function (in this case SUM) until you're happy with your WHERE clause. Start with:

```
SELECT id, value FROM table WHERE <conditions>
```

And look at the results you have. Once you have all the rows you want and none of the rows you don't, drop id from the column list and wrap value in your aggregate function (SUM).

Yes, you can use a condition like IN (1,2,3,4) to select each row you're after. You can also use ANDs, ORs, and other conditions to be as complicated as you want.